# Paradox: Two completely different values for $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1-n^2}+\frac{2}{1-n^2}+...+\frac{n}{1-n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fake-proofs, paradoxes

I am asked to evaluate the following question:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1-n^2}+\frac{2}{1-n^2}+...+\frac{n}{1-n^2}\right)$$

I did the following:

Using the property: Limit of a sum is the sum of limits, I take on each term separately.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{1-n^2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}-1}) = \frac{0}{-1} = 0.$$

Similarly each term evaluates to $0$ despite the dependence on n:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n}{1-n^2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\frac{n}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}-1}) = 0.$$

I checked the answer and it said -$\frac{1}{2}.$ I checked the complete solution:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{1-n^2}+\frac{2}{1-n^2}+...+\frac{n}{1-n^2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1+2+...+n}{1-n^2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{1-n^2}) = -\frac12.$$

Obviously, only one answer is ryt [hoping that the limit of an expression is a uniques number]. Both the deductions seem quite logical to me. The only plausible mistake i have noticed is $1+2+...+n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is only true for $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z$.

Solve the paradox.

Comment: When you do it for each term separately, you forget to consider that the numerator of the later terms depend on $n$.

Comment: It's more that the _number_ of terms depends on n.

Comment: "Limit of a sum is the sum of limits". This is true only for finite sums. But since your sum depends on $n$ it is not actually finite.

Comment: @Michael Burr Which sum?

Comment: You show that the individual terms in a sum go to zero.  Your sum, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ becomes $0\cdot\infty$, which is indeterminate.

Comment: As a simpler version of the same phenomenon, consider the sum
$$\frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$$
where the number of terms is $n$.

Comment: @Michael Burr I have edited the question. Now the $0.\infty$ indeterminate problem does not arise [i think].

Comment: Your second result is correct. It is enough to observe that $n(n-1)/2$ holds for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @quasi But i think the $0.\infty$ indeterminate form arises in that simpler version, whereas it does not [i hope] in my question.

Comment: @Masacroso Why is that?

Comment: @Basti Why does not the property "Limit of a sum is the sum of limits" hold when $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Basti's point was that the *number* of terms in your sum depends on $n$. The law "limit of a sum is the sum of limits" holds only for a fixed, finite number of summands.

Comment: @Reese Ok, got that now. Thanks.

Comment: Why not check some large $n$ and [see](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+k%2F(1-1000%5E2)+as+k+goes+from+1+to+1000) [what](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+k%2F(1-1000000%5E2)+as+k+goes+from+1+to+1000000) [happens](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+k%2F(1-1000000000%5E2)+as+k+goes+from+1+to+1000000000)? This is of course not a proof, but it may help build your intuition for these kinds of problems...

Comment: The reason that "the limit of a sum = the sum of the limits" doesn't hold when the number of terms is not a fixed positive integer is because you can't _prove_ it. How do we know that it can't be proved? Easy -- your examples show that!

Comment: I think that the problem would be clearer writing $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i {1-n^2}=\frac 1 {1-n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you cite, "Limit of a sum is the sum of limits", does not apply here. That is for a sum of a fixed, finite number of terms. Formally, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^Ma_k(n)=\sum_{k=1}^M\lim_{n\to\infty}a_k(n)$$ The important part is $M$ is a fixed constant.

Your situation is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k(n)$$

Note that even if you tried to take the limit to the terms inside, you would have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\lim_{n\to\infty}a_k(n)$$
which makes no sense. Since $n$ is the index variable for the limit, it has no meaning outside the limit, and could not appear as the sum's upper index.

Comment: You are right, i guess. +1.

Comment: The second solution you posted is correct. The limit is a limit of integers approaching infinity, not of real numbers approaching infinity. So there is no issue with the $n(n+1)/2$ expression.

Comment: How do you know it is a limit of integers? The question does not mention anything like that.

Comment: How would $\left(\frac{1}{1-n^2}+\frac{2}{1-n^2}+...+\frac{n}{1-n^2}\right)$ make any sense if $n$ is allowed to not be an integer? What does $\left(\frac{1}{1-n^2}+\frac{2}{1-n^2}+...+\frac{15.36}{1-15.36^2}\right)$ mean? Aside from that, $n$ is conventionally used as a variable that only takes integer or natural number values. And $x$ is conventionally used for a variable that can take general real values.